# PowerBI Dax Measure: Error returning table of multiple values when a single is expected

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm stuck on a DAX formula I have to fix regarding a Switch(Allselected) statement.

This measure exists out of 2 underlying measures. Let's call them A, B and C. This first one (top in hierarchy being)

**A:** BUDGET AMOUNT

```
Budget Amount = SWITCH(ALLSELECTED('>BudgetType'[-Value]),
"Original",[Budget Amount (Original)],
"Updated",[Budget Amount (Updated)])
```

The measures (original and updated) are as follows: **B:**

```
Budget Amount (Original) = sumx(FILTER(ERP_Budget_Details, ERP_Budget_Details[ERP_Budget.FOriginal]=TRUE),
ERP_Budget_Details[FAmount])
```

and **C:** UPDATED:

```
Budget Amount (Original) = Sumx(FILTER(ERP_Budget_Details,ERP_Budget_Details[ERP_Budget.FOriginal]=TRUE),
ERP_Budget_Details[FAmount])
```

Seperately when adding either **B** or **C** to the visual they work fine. However, when I try to use **A** I get the following error:

> Calculation error in Measure: "A Table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected"

Does anyone have any experience solving this issue, or see any error in my A code, that causes this to happen?

Would appreciate it!

Comment: Remove ALLSELECTED -> this is a table function

Comment: Sorry I'm a real noob but how would it then look like? I cannot refer to a table column without the allselected function. ('>BudgetType'[-Value]) , but this is what it needs to be depended on.

Comment: Try SELECTEDVALUE -> this take value from the current row.

Comment: This seems to get rid of the error, I have to let the user run several tests to ensure it works. thanks a bunch!